# How can we share data between two components - both are completely separate components. (which are not in child -parent relationship)

Tags: angular7

How can we share data between two components - both are completely separate components? (which are not in a child-parent relationship)

I want to show my registration component's variable 'totalReg' value in my header component. Both files are below.

This is my reg.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/reg.service';
import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';
@Component({

templateUrl: 'reg.component.html'
})
export class RegComponent {



    constructor(

    private userService: UserService,
    ) { }
@Output() totalReg: any;
register(event: any) {

    this.userService.create(event.target.username.value)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.totalReg = data['data'].userId;
                console.log(this.totalReg); // Navigate to the 
listing aftr registration done successfully

            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

This is my header.component.ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is html of my header component header.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<mat-toolbar>  
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/reg']">Registration</a> 
   </li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/users']">All Users</a> 
   </li>

                </ul>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <span>{{totalReg}}</span>
    </div>
```

header component should show the value of totalReg .

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with help of service class.

you are already using the UserService in **`RegComponent`** , so use the same service in the **`HeaderComponent`** to get the data.

> **HeaderComponent.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  totalReg: any;

  constructor(private service : UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.totalReg = this.service.totalRg;
  }

}
```

> **RegComponent.ts**

```
export class RegComponent {

@Output() totalReg: any;

constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

register(event: any) {
   this.userService.create(event.target.username.value)
        .subscribe(data => {
               this.totalReg = data['data'].userId;
               console.log(this.totalReg); // Navigate to the listing aftr registration done successfully
               this.service.totalRg = this.totalReg;
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

you are already using a class in  service class you need add the variable as totalRg

> **UserService.ts**

```
export class UserService {

  totalRg:any;

  constructor() { }

  create(name: any) {
    return ....//
  }
}
```

Comment: this.totalReg = this.service.totalReg; showing error on this line

totalReg is not declared in service class.

Comment: what's the error you are getting... ? and make sure that your `register()` executing before `HeaderComponent` ngOnInit().

Comment: No, my header onInit is executing before register ...its header part of page so obviously it will load first...doing same as you declared totalReg in service but still  not getting solution .

Comment: In that case you need get the data in the `HeaderComponent` and then use it in `RegComponent`. if not that case use `Eventemitter` to solve this issue.

Comment: yes thats what I am asking , can you update your code so I can get help .